# Executing task on its own is working but not when executed from another one

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have three `Gradle` tasks if I execute them one by one on its own then its working. But when I execute them from another task then its not working. Here is how my task looks like

```kotlin
import com.github.gradle.node.npm.task.NpmTask

plugins {
    id("com.github.node-gradle.node") version "3.4.0"
}

// Executing this task on its own is working
tasks.register<NpmTask>("buildFrontEnd") {
    workingDir.set(file("${projectDir}/frontend"))
    args.set(listOf("run", "build"))
}

// Executing this task on its own is working
tasks.register<Delete>("cleanFrontEnd") {
    delete(
        fileTree("${projectDir}/backend/main/resources/static/js"),
    )
}

// Executing this task on its own is working
tasks.register<Copy>("copyFrontEnd") {
    into("$projectDir")
    copy {
        from("${projectDir}/frontend/dist/css")
        into("${projectDir}/backend/main/resources/static/css")
    }
    
    copy {
        from("${projectDir}/frontend/dist/js")
        into("${projectDir}/backend/main/resources/static/js")
    }
}

// This tasks is not executing "copyFrontEnd"
tasks.register("frontEndBuild") {
    dependsOn("buildFrontEnd", "cleanFrontEnd", "copyFrontEnd")
    tasks.findByName("copyFrontEnd")?.mustRunAfter("buildFrontEnd", "cleanFrontEnd")
    // Tried this too but it is not working
    // tasks.findByName("cleanFrontEnd")?.mustRunAfter("buildFrontEnd")
    // tasks.findByName("copyFrontEnd")?.mustRunAfter("cleanFrontEnd")
}
```

This is the output

```
> Task :cleanFrontEnd
> Task :copyFrontEnd NO-SOURCE
> Task :frontEndBuild

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 20s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

For `:copyFrontEnd` it is saying `NO-SOURCE` but if that is the case then why its working when executing on its own? Is there anyway to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

When you register a task, the bit inside the `{ }` block configures the task. This block will *always* run whenever the task is required.

```kotlin
tasks.register<Copy>("copyFrontEnd") {
    into("$projectDir")

    // these copy actions will ALWAYS run whenever Gradle configures this task
    copy {
        from("${projectDir}/frontend/dist/css")
        into("${projectDir}/backend/main/resources/static/css")
    }
    
    copy {
        from("${projectDir}/frontend/dist/js")
        into("${projectDir}/backend/main/resources/static/js")
    }
}
```

Because you've used `register` when creating the task, Gradle won't execute the task configuration block won't unless the task is required. But when it is, those copy actions will run immediately.

To add [task actions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#N18A72), which will actually do the work of the task, add them using `doLast { }` or `doFirst { }`.

```kotlin
tasks.register<Copy>("copyFrontEnd") {
    into("$projectDir")

    doLast {
        copy {
            from("${projectDir}/frontend/dist/css")
            into("${projectDir}/backend/main/resources/static/css")
        }
        copy {
            from("${projectDir}/frontend/dist/js")
            into("${projectDir}/backend/main/resources/static/js")
        }
    }
}
```

Now those copy actions will only run when the task runs.

This still won't work however...

##### `NO-SOURCE`

> Task did not need to execute its actions.
>
> Task has inputs and outputs, but no sources
>
> *https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:task_outcomes*

When you register a [`Copy` task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html), you need to specify what the *source* is.

```kotlin
tasks.register<Copy>("copyFrontEnd") {
    into("$projectDir")
    // from(...) // no from, no source - Gradle thinks "this task doesn't need to run"
}
```

In your case, you can specify the source as `"${projectDir}/frontend/dist/css"` and get rid of the two separate copy actions.

```kotlin
tasks.register<Copy>("copyFrontEnd") {
    from("${projectDir}/frontend/dist/")
    into("${projectDir}/backend/main/resources/static/css")
}
```

You might want to fiddle around with includes to only copy the `css/` and `js/` directories - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:copying_directories_example

#### Typesafe references

This last bit is unrelated, but I thought I'd include it as it can help make your buildscript clearer.

While you can reference task by their names, it's nicer to reference them by a variable. When you register a task, it returns a handle to that task.
You can use that handle to specify task dependencies.

```kotlin
val buildFrontEndTask: TaskProvider<NpmTask> = tasks.register<NpmTask>("buildFrontEnd") {
  // ...
}

val cleanFrontEndTask: TaskProvider<Delete> = tasks.register<Delete>("cleanFrontEnd") {
  // ...
}

val copyFrontEndTask: TaskProvider<Copy> = tasks.register<Copy>("copyFrontEnd") {
  // ...
}

tasks.register("frontEndBuild") {
  // here you can set the task dependencies based on the task providers
  dependsOn(buildFrontEndTask, cleanFrontEndTask, copyFrontEndTask)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Unfortunately splitting each `copy` to separate `task` will be too much. In question there are only two but actual code have 7 or 10 I think.

Comment: @nicholasnet Understood, that's easily possible to achieve in Gradle. Can you post a new question with your specific goal?

Comment: The goal is to make `frontendBuild` task run `copyFrontEndTask` at last. Task `copyFrontEnd` can have multiple copy blocks in it unlike just 2 in the question.

Comment: Please create a new question with all the details. You might be able to do multiple copy actions in a single `Copy` task, or you can create a normal task with multiple `copy {}` blocks. But it's hard to know for sure what is best without seeing more details.

Comment: All I am looking for is to make `frontendBuild` task run `copyFrontEnd` at last in existing question without splitting each `copy{}` block into separate task.